# Flask + flask-restful gives strange error

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

I've used Flask in a couple of projects, but never used the flask-restful package when creating restul APIs - so I thought I should give it a try.

However, I've come across a weird error that I can't understand - and the API doesn't work at all. The error message says

```
{
    "message": "Not Found. You have requested this URI [/api/v1.0/items] but did you mean /api/v1.0/items ?", 
    "status": 404
}
```

**run.py**

```
from my_project import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host=0.0.0.0, debug=app.config['DEBUG'])
```

**my_project/_ *init* _.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from my_project.base import blueprint as BaseBluePrint
from my_project.api import blueprint as ApiBluePrint
app.register_blueprint(BaseBluePrint)
app.register_blueprint(ApiBluePrint, url_prefix='/api/v1.0')
```

**my_project/api/_ *init* _.py**

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask.ext import restful

blueprint = Blueprint('api', __name__)
api = restful.Api(blueprint)

class ItemList(restful.Resource):
    def get(self):
        return false


api.add_resource(ItemList, '/items', endpoint='items')
```

What can cause this? Whatever I do, the error remains. Looking at the `url_map` from Flask, I can see my route in there - and it looks fine. When moving away from blueprints and keeping it all in one file, it works. Python v2.7 and flask-restful v0.2.12 (installed from pip on Ubuntu Precise).

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is a hidden character somewhere, either in your request, or the endpoint you setup. Try retyping it all - if not, open an issue here: https://github.com/twilio/flask-restful

Comment: Try `return False`

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

Add **ERROR_404_HELP=False** in your environment:

```
app.config['ERROR_404_HELP'] = False
```

Answer (score -1):

I had similar problems related to trailing slashes, e.g. i defined api.com/endpoint and was sending request to api.com/endpoint/ and was having 404 errors.

Solution was to configure Flask application not to be strict about trailing slashes by: `app.url_map.strict_slashes = False`

Comment: This solution didn't work for me. I found a workaround by making the uri definition less strict and catch the error by myself. But still the weird error message. Mentionned as a closed issue in flask-restful project in github https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/449 and here https://github.com/flask-restful/flask-restful/issues/780